# Error line link broken in the Resharper 5.1 unit tests session window

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, resharper

I've got a quite annoying problem with the links that point to the error line when a unit test fails.

The test are running normally. But it would be good if the link were working. I have to check the line, find the file and go to that particular line.

It's not that important, but it's nice to have.

The content of a link is: about:projectfile%3A4F7C8F8A-1D52-49C1-8220-B9AE77BAF564%2Ff%3AUpdateCustomerTests.cs%3F879%3F1

The name of the file is in there, but I'm not sure whether the rest of the content is correct.

Hope someone knows how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Just stumbled over this, too.

It is caused by the Internet security options for the Internet Zone.

To fix this, go to **Internet Options -> Security -> Internet Zone Custom Level** and Activate **"Websites in less privileged web content zone can navigate into this zone"**.

found the solution at [jetBrains forums](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5290261?tstart=0#5290261%20%22jetBrains%20forums)